Mouse speed 4/11 in windows to Ubuntu 22.04
I just installed dconf-editor on my Ubuntu 22.04 to configure a custom mouse speed, but I'm not sure what mouse speed value in Ubuntu is equivalent to 4/11 in Windows.
dconf-editor settings:

And in the picture that I'm adjusting the settings in my dconf-editor, is my mouse acceleration set to 0? I'm not sure.
